# AngularJS call scope function to 'refresh' scope model

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, mean

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and can't seem to find a solution.
I have a simple listing in my view, fetched from MongoDB and I want it to refresh whenever I call the delete or update function.
Although it seems simple that I should be able to call a previously declared function within the same scope, it just doesn't work.

I tried setting the getDispositivos on a third service, but then the Injection gets all messed up. Declaring the function simply as var function () {...} but it doesn't work as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('appDispositivos', []);

    /* My service */
    myApp.service('dispositivosService', 
        ['$http',
            function($http) {
                //...

            this.getDispositivos = function(response) {
                $http.get('http://localhost:3000/dispositivos').then(response);     
            }

            //...
        }
    ]
);

myApp.controller('dispositivoController',
    ['$scope', 'dispositivosService',
        function($scope, dispositivosService) {

            //This fetches data from Mongo...
            $scope.getDispositivos = function () {
                dispositivosService.getDispositivos(function(response) {
                    $scope.dispositivos = response.data;
                });
            };

            //... and on page load it fills in the list
            $scope.getDispositivos();

            $scope.addDispositivo = function() {
                dispositivosService.addDispositivo($scope.dispositivo);
                $scope.getDispositivos(); //it should reload the view here...
                $scope.dispositivo = '';
            };

            $scope.removeDispositivo = function (id) {
                dispositivosService.removerDispositivo(id);
                $scope.getDispositivos(); //... here
            };

            $scope.editDispositivo = function (id) {
                dispositivosService.editDispositivo(id);
                $scope.getDispositivos(); //... and here.
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: try calling $scope.getDispositivos(); after you get a response from add remove or edit

Answer (score 0):

On service

```
this.getDispositivos = function(response) {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/dispositivos');     
        }
```

on controller

```
$scope.addDispositivo = function() {
            dispositivosService.addDispositivo($scope.dispositivo).then(function(){
            $scope.getDispositivos(); //it should reload the view here...
            $scope.dispositivo = '';
    });     
};
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked. Later on I found that the GET request does execute, asynchronously however. This means that it loads the data into $scope before the POST request has finished, thus not including the just-included new data.

The solution is to synchronize the tasks (somewhat like in multithread programming), using the $q module, and to work with deferred objects and promises. So, on my service

```
.factory('dispositivosService',
['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
        return {
            getDispositivos: function (id) {
                getDef = $q.defer();
                $http.get('http://myUrlAddress'+id)
                .success(function(response){
                    getDef.resolve(response);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    getDef.reject('Failed GET request');
                });
                return getDef.promise;
            }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

On my controller:

```
$scope.addDispositivo = function() {
            dispositivosService.addDispositivo($scope.dispositivo)
            .then(function(){
                dispositivosService.getDispositivos()
                .then(function(dispositivos){
                    $scope.dispositivos = dispositivos;
                    $scope.dispositivo = '';
                })
            });
        };
```

Being my 'response' object a $q.defer type object, then I can tell Angular that the response is asynchronous, and .then(---).then(---); logic completes the tasks, as the asynchronous requests finish.